# Get the total value from a summation value of column, MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Okay, I learned about this query 2 days ago:-

```sql
SELECT SUM(DTotal) AS Monthly FROM bdailytotal
```

but how I'm going to view the total value of the summation? I had been searching for this but most of the answers I get is for PHP. Can someone show me how to assign that total value to a variable in VB.NET?

Or teach me how to assign that total value to another table.

Comment: What do you mean by view? It's all there in the query.

Comment: Yeah I know, the total is in the Monthly but how do I call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this with `ExecuteScalar()`:

```
Dim objConn As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
Dim objCmd As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
Dim strConnString,strSQL As String

strConnString = "Server=localhost;User Id=root; Password=root; Database=mydatabase;"
objConn = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(strConnString)
objConn.Open()

strSQL = "SELECT SUM(DTotal) AS Monthly FROM bdailytotal"

objCmd = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand()
With objCmd
.Connection = objConn
.CommandType = CommandType.Text
.CommandText = strSQL
End With

Dim myScalar As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(objCmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try The following:

```
While dr.Read()
Dim monthly = dr("Monthly")
End While

MsgBox(monthly)
```